# Convert gui object to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm an absolute begginer in the use of R and I wanted to ask you a question :

I created a pop-up window where users can enter a code from 01 to 09.

I'd like to use the result and convert it to a dataframe as an output.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Dam.

Here's the code I used :

library(svDialogs)

test <- dlgInput("Veuillez entrer un code essence")
test2<-data.frame(test)
test2

And the error message I get :

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :
impossible to automatically convert ‘c("nativeGUI", "textCLI", "gui", "environment")’ as a dataframe (data.frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the documentation : https://www.sciviews.org/svDialogs/reference/dlg_input.html

```
library(svDialogs)

test <- dlgInput("Veuillez entrer un code essence")$res
test2<-data.frame(test) 
test2
```

Note the use of `$res`